Did Wordsworth read William Jones's translation of Kalidasa?
In Finding the Raga, Amit Chaudhuri writes:

Meghdut literally means 'cloud-messenger'. In Kalidasa's poem, a lover asks a cloud to carry with it a message from him to his loved one, who lives in the city of Alaka. The long poem describes the lover's imagining of the cloud's journey. The cloud, in other words, has become, as it was for Wordsworth (who may well have read Kalidasa in William Jones's translation), a figure for the imagination.
Chaudhuri, Amit. Finding the Raga: an Improvisation on Indian Music. New York: NYRB, 2020. p. 81

I'm skeptical about this passage for several reasons. First, as written, it leaves the unsuspecting reader with the impression that Jones translated Meghadūta. He did not. He translated Abhijñanaśakuntalam in 1789, but to the best of my knowledge and belief, this is the only work of Kalidasa's that Jones translated into English. Again to the best of my knowledge and belief, the first English translation of Meghadūta was H H Wilson's 1814 rendition. Since Wordsworth's "I wandered lonely as a cloud" was written in 1804, he could not have had Meghadūta in mind. Granted, Chaudhuri is careful not to say that Wordsworth could have read Meghadūta specifically. He says only that Wordsworth could have read Kālidāsa in Jones's translation, leaving the exact work artfully unspecified. This allows Chaudhuri to have it both ways: he can conjure up a spurious connection between Wordsworth's cloud and Kālidāsa's, yet leave himself wiggle room to claim that any reader making this connection is misinterpreting what he actually wrote.
The dubiety of this sleight-of-hand aside, Chaudhuri's "may well have read" bears interrogation. Jones's Sacontalā, the first English translation of a Sanskrit play, was indeed a best-seller. Thomas Jefferson is known to have owned a copy. But if there is any actual evidence that Wordsworth was familiar with this translation, Chaudhuri does not provide it. So: Is there any documented evidence that Wordsworth had read Jones's translation of Kālidāsa? Does Wordsworth refer to Sacontalā in any of his letters or publications? Failing that, are there any verbal echoes or allusions in any of Wordsworth's poetry that can be traced back to Jones's translation? Or is this another rhetorical ploy whereby Chaudhuri conjures up a connection between Wordsworth and Kālidāsa when there isn't actually one to be made?
Additional tags: sanskrit-language, meghaduta, translation, abhjnanasakuntalam, sacontala, intertextuality

You could replace the tags amit-chaudhuri and finding-the-raga with sacontala and meghaduta since you seem more interested in what Wordsworth may have read than in Chaudhuri's book, which is merely the trigger for that question.
